# Opening link using Delegate in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to enable my links to be opened in a web browser.

Everything works fine with the delegate in the for loop but inside the eventGen() method I tried to obtain the name of the link clicked in which one link brings the string `nameOfLink` as ...

> "System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel, Text: Quora For Programmers"

on using an if statement to verify the selected name and open the link all the if statements are always skipped even if i change the text to

```
nameOfLink.Equals("Quora For Programmers");


namespace VisitedSites
{
    public partial class frmRecentlyVisitedSites : Form
    {
        // Create an array of Link labels
        LinkLabel[] sites = new LinkLabel[3];

        // Create links with the tool tips
        LinkLabel lnkQuora = new LinkLabel();
        ToolTip quora = new ToolTip();

        // Create links with the tool tips
        LinkLabel lnkIndeed = new LinkLabel();
        ToolTip indeed = new ToolTip();

        // Create links with the tool tips
        LinkLabel lnkHackerRank = new LinkLabel();
        ToolTip hackerRank = new ToolTip();

        public frmRecentlyVisitedSites()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void frmRecentlyVisitedSites_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Populate the array with links 
            sites[0] = lnkQuora;
            quora.SetToolTip(lnkQuora, "Quora For Questions!");
            sites[1] = lnkIndeed;
            indeed.SetToolTip(lnkIndeed, "Qualified For Jobs!");
            sites[2] = lnkHackerRank;
            hackerRank.SetToolTip(lnkHackerRank, "Comfortable Coding?");

            // Configure the LinkLabel's properties. 
            this.lnkQuora.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(37, 36);
            this.lnkQuora.AutoSize = true;
            this.lnkQuora.Text = "Quora For Programmers";

            // Configure the LinkLabel's properties. 
            this.lnkIndeed.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(37, 56);
            this.lnkIndeed.AutoSize = true;
            this.lnkIndeed.Text = "Indeed For The Skilled";

            // Configure the LinkLabel's properties. 
            this.lnkHackerRank.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(37, 76);
            this.lnkHackerRank.AutoSize = true;
            this.lnkHackerRank.Text = "Hacker Rank For The Robust";

            for (int i = 0; i < sites.Length; i++)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(sites[i]);
                sites[i].LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(EventGen);
            }

        }
        private void EventGen(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Determine the name of the link
            string nameOfLink = sender.ToString();

            // process the link depending on the name
            if(nameOfLink.Equals("System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel, Text:Quora For Programmers", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                lnkQuora.LinkVisited = true;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.quora.com/");
            }
            else if(nameOfLink.Equals("System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel, Text:Indeed For The Skilled", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                lnkQuora.LinkVisited = true;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.indeed.com/");
            }
            else if(nameOfLink.Equals("System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel, Text:Hacker Rank For The Robust", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                lnkQuora.LinkVisited = true;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.hackerrank.com/");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on a `Forms.LinkLabel` object and doing checks on that string is a bad thing to do.. Just try to cast it back to a `LinkLabel` object and operate on its properties. I'm sure if it's a "LinkLabel" that form-control has a designated property for the link, which you can easily set through the UI Designer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried your code, you are missing one space
is

```
System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel, Text: Quora For Programmers
```

instead of

```
System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel, Text:Quora For Programmers
```

Answer (score 0):

why not add the links, e.g. "https://www.quora.com/" to the linkdata like link.LinkData = "https://www.quora.com/", and then open that link using Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData as string)?

Comment: // Determine the name of the link
            string nameOfLink = sender.ToString();   This is where the problem is ..If it matches the strings in the if statements all will open

Comment: sorry, did you try something like this?<p>this.lnkQuora..LinkData = "https://www.quora.com/";

private void EventGen(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData as string);
}